# Building a board game using canvas + css animations

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Hi I'm attempting to build a boardgame where where you roll dice(math.random) and your token moves spaces depending on the result of the roll. I decided to use canvas to draw the board itself, but I am stuck on how I should get the tokens to move. I've mapped out the coordinates for every tile (bottom:'', left:''), and also created an array for the dice roll results to collect. I guess my question is how do I make those results add up, and also how do I make that Sum Total represent a coordinate on the board. Code to follow.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var tokenSum = [];
var tknSum = [];
var element = document.getElementById('rollbtnid');

if (canvas.getContext) {
  make_base();

  function make_base() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = '0.5x/SymBoardBrdr_1@0.5x.png';
    base_image.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    }
  }
} else {
  alert('Your browser doesnt support HTML canvas please upgrade it');
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const buttonDiceroll = document.querySelector('.rollbtn');

  function rollDice() {
    const dice = document.getElementById('dice');
    const status = document.getElementById('rollWords');

    const rollTotal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    const diceTotal = rollTotal;
    tokenSum.push(rollTotal);
    console.log(tokenSum);

    status.innerHTML = 'You rolled ' + diceTotal + '.';
  }

  buttonDiceroll.addEventListener('click', rollDice, false);
}, false);
```

```css
.redtoken {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 500px;
  left: 850px;
}

.bluetoken {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 790px;
  left: 200px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("0.5x/dragonscaleSmall@0.5x.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

#myCanvas {
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: white;
}

#rollWords {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 36pt;
}

.actionBx {
  height: 80%;
  width: 20%;
}

.statusbx {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 65%;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}

.narratebox {
  position: relative;
  left: 15%;
  bottom: 38%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
}

.rollbtn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80%;
  right: 20%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1.5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px 0px grey;
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="575" style="border:2px solid 
      #000000;"></canvas>
  <button class="rollbtn" id='rollbtnid'>
         <h5> Roll</h5>
      </button>
  <div class="statusbx" id="statusbxid">
    <h6 id='rollWords'></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="narratebox" id="narrateboxid">
    <h7 id='narrateWords'></h7>
  </div>
  <div class='redtoken' id='redtokenid'><img src='0.5x/SmLvTkn@0.5x.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='bluetoken' id='bluetokenid'><img src='0.5x/SmWhtTkn@0.5x.png'>
  </div>
  <script src="GoT_Canvas_test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Surely you need to add the Roll Button as a sprite which can then be moved around the canvas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's extremely hard to answer this question with 100% accuracy because you don't provide working example but here's how I would probably do it (if I understood your game correctly):

- store tiles in array `[{left: 0, top: 0}, {/* ... */}, /* ... */]`
- store current position as variable (correlates to index of tile in tiles array)
- if user rolls, add roll amount to current and you have new tile position

```js
// meta code
const tiles = [
  {left: 0, top: 0},
  {left: 10, top: 10},
  {left: 20, top: 20},
  {left: 30, top: 30},
  {left: 40, top: 40},
  {left: 50, top: 50},
  {left: 60, top: 60},
  {left: 70, top: 70},
  {left: 80, top: 80},
  {left: 90, top: 90},
  {left: 100, top: 100},
  {left: 110, top: 110},
  {left: 120, top: 120},
];

let rollHistory = [];
let currentPosition = 0; // starting positon

function rollDice() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}

// show roll history
const el = document.getElementById('roll-history');

function updateHistory(roll) {
  rollHistory.push(roll);
  el.innerHTML = '';
  rollHistory.forEach((record, i) => {
    const recordDiv = document.createElement('div');
    recordDiv.innerHTML = `${(i + 1)}: ${record}`;
    el.appendChild(recordDiv);
  });
}

// draw tiles
const tilesWrapper = document.getElementById('tiles-wrapper');

tiles.forEach(tile => {
  const tileDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tileDiv.className = 'tile';
  tileDiv.style.left = tile.left + 'px';
  tileDiv.style.top = tile.top + 'px';
  tilesWrapper.appendChild(tileDiv);
});


// button and position logic
const button = document.getElementById('roll-button');
const piece = document.getElementById('piece');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const roll = rollDice();
  updateHistory(roll);

  if (currentPosition + roll >= tiles.length) {
    // not enought tiles left, go to last
    currentPosition = tiles.length - 1;
  } else {
    currentPosition += roll;
  }
  
  piece.style.left = tiles[currentPosition].left + 'px';
  piece.style.top = tiles[currentPosition].top + 'px';
  
  // if on last, WIN!
  if (currentPosition === tiles.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(() => alert('You win!'), 1);
  }
});
```

```css
#roll-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 10px;
}

#piece {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
}

.tile {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.history {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<button id="roll-button">Roll</button>

<div class="history">
  History (move: roll) <br /> <br />
  <div id="roll-history"></div>
</div>

<div id="piece"></div>
<div id="tiles-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: You nailed it! That's exactly what I needed.  I've got those pieces moving across my board perfectly now. Thank you very much.    I've still got a lot ahead of me, but this was a major part I was stuck on.

Comment: You can also add more data to tile objects besides position and check them if piece lands on that tile, e.g if user has to draw a card, skip a move, shortcut, etc. Endless possibilities. Good luck!

Comment: oh like if I wanted to put a trap on them?   that's so cool. would I add it in the same curly brackets as the coordinates?

Comment: Just add more properties, e.g: `{left: 0, top: 0, data: {type: 'SKIP', numOfTurns: 2}}`.

Comment: ahh genius. so I could do {left:"", top: "", data: {type:'TRAP', left"-2", top:""}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the pixel positions of each tile and translate the player piece over time to the according tile position. Depending on the board you could also do it entirely using runtime math but for starters I would suggest storing them. Since it's a canvas you will have to clear and redraw the entire canvas after each frame since it will keep adding to the current frame otherwise. Ideally you should store the png as base64 and don't request it anew every time.